# No refrence for instructions strneh, lsreq, streqb

Tags: android, assembly, arm, android-source

I was looking at strcpy.S file in android platform at path libc/arch-arm/bionic, in this file there are many arm instructions which i am not able to understand, i am also referring ARM System Developers Guide.
Here except "tst" and "tstne" i am not able to find any refrence for others in any book or ARM refrence manual.

```
tst r2, #0xff00
iteet   ne
strneh  r2, [ip], #2
lsreq   r2, r2, #8
    r2, [ip]
tstne   r2, #0xff
```

Not only these instructions there are many others in different files also.

Does anyone have any idea what these instructions are ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*strneh* is a store command with some conditional execution/size specifier suffixes.  The ARM docs are a good place to start: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Chdehgih.html

If you google "arm conditional execution", you'll find a number of blogs/articles that may also help: http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/258-condition-codes-2-conditional-execution/

As for your *strneh" instruction:

- str = store
- ne = execute if not equal (Z flag clear)
- h = perform a half-word operation

Comment: Thanks for the links, Now if i have understood this correctly then these conditional flags i can attach with any arm instruction to work if that condition satisfies.

Comment: In general "yes", p.14 of this pdf provides a brief overview of conditional execution: http://simplemachines.it/doc/arm_inst.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The first instructions it the it-instruction from the thumb instructions set.

```
iteet   ne
```

This instruction marks the next three instructions to be conditional executable. The last three characters of the instruction make a pattern consisting of e (else) or t (then). The operand 'ne' specifies the condition to be evaluated.

The other three instructions are ordinary ARM instructions with conditionals:

```
strneh  r2, [ip], #2  ; store halfword if not equal
lsreq   r2, r2, #8    ; logical shift right if equal
tstne   r2, #0xff     ; test if not equal
```

These are the three instructions affected by the it-instruction. They come with ne/eq conditional flags as well.

As you can see the conditions of the it-instructions and the conditions of the other three instructions are in conflict to each other. This is a bug in the code. Most likely it hasn't been discovered before because the code-snippet is from the ARM-big-endian code, and I know of no android phone that uses ARM in big endian.

Btw, it's worthwhile to know why the conditions are given in the it-instruction and in the instructions itself. This is part of the unified arm assembly standard. On the ARM you have two modes of operation: Thumb mode (uses It-instruction, less powerful) and ARM-mode (more powerful, uses condition-flags in the instructions itself).

If you limit yourself to the capabilities of the thumb-mode it is possible to write code that would compile in thumb and ARM-mode. This is done here.

If you assemble for Thumb-mode the It-instruction will be used to control the conditions of the next three instruction, and the conditions within the instructions gets ignored. If you assemble to ARM-instruction set the It-instruction gets ignored and the conditions from the instruction itself will become active.

This works well as long as the it-instruction and the conditions in the arm-instructions match. As I said before this is not the case here, so it will either not work in thumb-mode, arm-mode or both :-)

Comment: Thanks Nils, now i have clarity with thumb mode and conditional flags